# How to move an object to another scope through checkbox using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, checkbox

I've lost in thought. I have a checkbox that I want to use to transfer a corresponding object to another scope on my page. Moreover, I want only to transfer one field of this checked object. I had used earlier Ajax by creating a .json file and then I responded to it in my controller. In my case input checkbox doesn't seem to have a `remote: true` option.

**views/tasks/_index.html**

```
<h3>Tasks database</h3>

<table>

  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
    <tr class='tasks' id="task_<%= task.id %>">

    #Some stuff

      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class='check' data-id="<%= task.id %>" >
      </td>

    </tr>

  <% end %>

</table>

<h3>Completed</h3>

<div class="complete-tasks">
</div>
```

Hence, I'm trying to accomplish that using an `event` via javascript.

So far I've managed to write some javascript code that moving my entire object.

**application.js**

```
  $(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
        $('.check').on('change', function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        task = $(this).closest("tr");
        $('.complete-tasks').last().after(task);
        }
      });
    })
```

[image]

But I want to relocate only one 'title' field using Ajax. Can someone please explain me how to accomplish that? I suspect I need to pass in some   id's in checkbox and to define $.ajax.

**models/task.rb**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :complete, -> { where(complete: true) }
  scope :incomplete, -> { where(complete: nil) }

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: You want to relocate only the the title cell into the .complete-tasks div and not the table row?

Comment: @MinusFour Yep. I wanted to do this. But I can't figure out how to get it done. Ok, we can omit this. Suppose I want to move a row. How can I do this with Ajax?

Comment: You want to do a HttpRequest and then move the table row/title cell?

Comment: @MinusFour Yes, that's it. But I want it without refreshing the page. That's why I want to apply Ajax.

Comment: @MinusFour As much as I know Ajax uses XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is make the request to the url and then move the table row/title cell.

```
 $(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
        $('.check').on('change', function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            //Url is the site you want to hit.
            var jqXHR = $.ajax(url);
            var element = this;
            jqXHR.done(function(data){
                //Ajax finish here.
                task = $(element).closest("tr");
                $('.complete-tasks').last().after(task);
            });
        }
      });
    });
```

Edit: Fixed context use.

Check the jQuery documentation on how to set up the jqXHR properly:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for a clarification. I'm just curious am I supposed to add some data-url attribute to checkbox line?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do. You could add a data attribute with the url for each checkbox so you can just pick it up and pass it to the ajax call. However, I would only use this approach if I were to hit completely different urls. Otherwise, I could just use a string literal that is the base of the url and concatenate it with different parameters. `'http://www.mywebsite.com/modules/tasks/' + idTask + '/complete';`